# How can the PCA algorithm be implemented for feature extraction of captured live packets (using the jpcap library), in Java?

Tags: java, weka, pca, packet, pcap

As in several research papers [[1]](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/05/feature-extraction-using-pca/),  [[2]](https://qlucore.com/news/the-benefits-of-principal-component-analysis-pca),  [[3]](https://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com/2019/03/advantages-and-disadvantages-of_4.html) it seems appropriate to make use of the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) algorithm for feature extraction. To attempt to accomplish this I have produced a traffic sniffer program in java making use of the jpcap library (snippet below), which is able to extract various features from live network traffic.

But I have not found any way to actually implement this, as existing approaches (snippets below) all seem to operate on non-live pre-organised datasets such as in the form of ARFF files.

I have seen a number of research papers  [[4]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0af4/1cdc08708d643f6de11d875ef3d08c3666c2.pdf),  [[5]](http://airccse.org/journal/jcsit/1210ijcsit13.pdf),  [[6]](https://cordis.europa.eu/docs/projects/cnect/3/619633/080/deliverables/001-ONTICD432017021010final.pdf) that reference the use of the PCA algorithm in combination jpcap library, that said I have not been able to find an explanation as to how this was accomplished this.

**To be clear:**

My question is, how can I implement PCA (using any approach) to extract features from live packets (attained via used of the pcap library referenced above) in Java? as others have accomplished (some examples have been referenced above)

*Sniffer Example* (using Jpcap Library)

**Sniffer.java**

```
import jpcap.JpcapCaptor;
import jpcap.NetworkInterface;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import jpcap.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.util.List;
public class Sniffer {
    public static NetworkInterface[] NETWORK_INTERFACES;
    public static JpcapCaptor CAP;
    jpcap_thread THREAD;
    public static int INDEX = 0;
    public static int flag = 0;
    public static int COUNTER = 0;
    static boolean CaptureState = false;
    public static int No = 0;
    JpcapWriter writer = null;
    List<Packet> packetList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Object[]> packetInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void CapturePackets() {
        THREAD = new jpcap_thread() {
            public Object construct() {
                try {
                    CAP = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(NETWORK_INTERFACES[INDEX], 65535, false, 20);
                    // writer = JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(CAP, "captureddata");
                    if ("UDP".equals(filter_options.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                        CAP.setFilter("udp", true);
                    } else if ("TCP".equals(filter_options.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                        CAP.setFilter("tcp", true);
                    } else if ("ICMP".equals(filter_options.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                        CAP.setFilter("icmp", true);
                    }
                    while (CaptureState) {
                        CAP.processPacket(1, new PacketContents());
                        packetList.add(CAP.getPacket());
                    }
                    CAP.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
                return 0;
            }
            public void finished() {
                this.interrupt();
            }
        };
        THREAD.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaptureState = true;
        CapturePackets();
    }
    public void saveToFile() {
        THREAD = new jpcap_thread() {
            public Object construct() {
                writer = null;
                try {
                    CAP = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(NETWORK_INTERFACES[INDEX], 65535, false, 20);
                    writer = JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(CAP, "captured_data.txt");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Sniffer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < No; i++) {
                    writer.writePacket(packetList.get(i));
                }
                return 0;
            }
            public void finished() {
                this.interrupt();
            }
        };
        THREAD.start();
    }
}
```

**PacketContents.java**

```
import jpcap.PacketReceiver;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import jpcap.packet.TCPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.UDPPacket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jpcap.packet.ICMPPacket;

public class PacketContents implements PacketReceiver {

    public static TCPPacket tcp;
    public static UDPPacket udp;
    public static ICMPPacket icmp;

    public void recievePacket(Packet packet) {
    }

    @Override
    public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {

        if (packet instanceof TCPPacket) {
            tcp = (TCPPacket) packet;

            Sniffer.packetInfo.add(new Object[] { sniffer.No, tcp.length, tcp.src_ip, tcp.dst_ip, "TCP", tcp.src_port,
                    tcp.dst_port, tcp.ack, tcp.ack_num, tcp.data, tcp.sequence, tcp.offset, tcp.header });

            sniffer.No++;

        } else if (packet instanceof UDPPacket) {

            udp = (UDPPacket) packet;

            Sniffer.packetInfo.add(new Object[] { sniffer.No, udp.length, udp.src_ip, udp.dst_ip, "UDP", udp.src_port,
                    udp.dst_port, udp.data, udp.offset, udp.header });

            sniffer.No++;

        } else if (packet instanceof ICMPPacket) {

            icmp = (ICMPPacket) packet;

            Sniffer.packetInfo.add(new Object[] { sniffer.No, icmp.length, icmp.src_ip, icmp.dst_ip, "ICMP",
                    icmp.checksum, icmp.header, icmp.offset, icmp.orig_timestamp, icmp.recv_timestamp,
                    icmp.trans_timestamp, icmp.data });

            sniffer.No++;

        }
    }
}
```

*Using the Weka Library to execute the PCA algorithm on an ARFF file*

**WekaPCA.java**

```
package project;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;
import weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader;
import java.io.File;
import org.math.plot.FrameView;
import org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;
import org.math.plot.PlotPanel;
import org.math.plot.plots.ScatterPlot;
import weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents;
import weka.attributeSelection.Ranker;

public class PCA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Load data
            String InputFilename = "kdd99.arff";

            ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File(InputFilename));
            Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

            // Perform PCA
            PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
            pca.setVarianceCovered(1.0);
            pca.setTransformBackToOriginal(false);
            pca.buildEvaluator(data);

            // Show transformed data
            Instances transformedData = pca.transformedData();
            System.out.println(transformedData);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is your question more about PCA itself, or implementing in Java?

Comment: My question is, how can I implement PCA (using any approach) to extract features from live packets (attained via used of the pcap library referenced above) in Java? as others have accomplished (some examples have been referenced above)

Comment: The purpose of PCA is to reduce the dimensionality of the features that you are examining. It is especially helpful if some of the features are largely redundant with others. Perhaps your question might be: what features from the live packets can I extract?

Comment: @rajah9 All I need, is to see an implementation of PCA making use of the packet related output produced via the jpcap library in Java. This is specifically where I have been having trouble. Do you know how to do this? (if so I would be very appreciative if you could provide such an example) Thanks